# Connection to mongodb via python

Tags: python, mongodb, docker

I created a mongodb instance in a docker container and I am struggling to get a connection to change anything in the database. Does anyone have a hint, what might be wrong?

Here is the docker run command:

```bash
# Start the docker container
echo "mongodb password in file" $(pwd)/mongodb.pass
docker run \
    -p 27017:27017 \
    --restart unless-stopped \
    --name mongodb \
    -v airlist:/data/db \
    -v $(pwd)/mongodb.pass:/mongodb.pass \
    -d \
    --network airfetch \
    -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=airfetch \
    -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=airlist27101978 \
    mongo:latest
```

Using this docker container, I want to access the database.
I run this python script on the host of the docker container. Since the port is exposed, this should work. Indeed, when I just pass `auth_string=mongodb://localhost:27017`, I get a response from the `server_info` method, but cannot insert any records or databases.

```py
import pymongo
import urllib.parse

username = urllib.parse.quote_plus('airfetch')
password = urllib.parse.quote_plus('airlist27101978')
auth_db = 'admin'
auth_source='?authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority'
auth_string = f"mongodb://{username}:{password}@localhost:27017/{auth_db}{auth_source}"
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient(auth_string)
```

However, I get the error message:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Authentication failed.', 'code': 18, 'codeName': 'AuthenticationFailed'}
```

Comment: please provide DockerFile

Comment: There is no Dockerfile. I just run the official mongodb container from the container registry `mongo:latest`in the above script

Comment: add authsource as detailed in the answer hope it works :)

Comment: That was a typo, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to add authsource:

> ?authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority :

From:

```
auth_string = f"mongodb://{username}:{password}@localhost:27017/{auth_db}"
```

To:

```
auth_string = f"mongodb://{username}:{password}@localhost:27017/{auth_db}?authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

Comment: Did you test this on your environment? I get the same error message

Comment: yeah, please feel free to update to update your question with all the required info. for instance where are you adding the authsource ? i guess inside the container

Comment: I updated the information. It is outside the container, but this should not be the issue

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: I did not delete the volume after I changed the password. Apparently, the credentials are stored in `data/db` within the container.

Comment: Use a MakeFile to prune,build and push :) so you will never forget